# Loading Qiskit account in the Jupyter notebook gives RequestsApiError error

Tags: programming, qiskit

I successfully installed qiskit,
yet am unable to load my account in the Jupyter notebook.

Each time I load my account in Jupyter notebook here is the response I get

> RequestsApiError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
>   https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/users/loginWithToken.
>   LOGIN_FAILED, Error code: LOGIN_FAILED.

What causes this?

Answer (score 2):

This is normally caused by incorrect credentials being used. To fix this you can generate a new API key and update your saved credentials to use this instead.

You can do this by navigating to https://quantum-computing.ibm.com and getting your API key from the `My Account` section. In a notebook then run `IBMQ.save_account('YOUR API KEY', overwrite=True)`. This will remove any incorrect credentials from your system and then the login should work.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me. This worked for me.

```
IBMQ.delete_account()
```

By deleting account, you should not be having any active accounts from IBMQ api. check that by getting active accounts

```
IBMQ.active_account()
```

After which generate a new token in your IBMQ experience website, https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account

And then copy the new token, save that as a variable (I saved it into API_KEY), then save account in IBMQ

```
IBMQ.save_account(API_KEY, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sign up an IBMid account by your original mail address will fix it.